# Recursive string modification in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string. I need to make every other line reversed. If count is 2, it should display:

```
"Hola mi amigo \nogima im aloH"
```

If count is 3, it should display:

```
"Hola mi amigo \nogima im aloH \nHola mi amigo"
```

and so on. What is the shortest way to perform string modification between every other `"\n"`?

My hunch is to use regex. In addition to regex solution, is there any non-regex solution? I would like to see both for comparison.

```
def hola(count) 
  if COUNT IS LESS THAN 2
    return false
  elsif ODD
    (("Hola mi amigo ")*((count-1)/2) + "\n") * count 
  elsif EVEN
    (("Hola mi amigo ")*(count/2) + "\n") * count 
  end 
end
```

Comment: @sawa count in hola(count) is the variable, an integer, that user inputs. Count in if COUNT IS... is what the code is expected to do in human language, without actually writing the actual code; i.e.: laziness.

Comment: Iggy, @sawa is saying, "Please edit your question to define `count`". When questions arise, it's best to edit your question rather than trying to answer in comments. Not everyone reads comments or should be expected to do so. Questions should be self-contained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are no restrictions in the implementation, then try something like this:

```
string = "Hola mi amigo"
reversed_string = string.reverse
count.times.map { |i| i.odd? ? reversed_string : string }.join "\n"
```

`times.map` will create an enumerator. The next block will check if the current index is odd or even; in the first case, it will reverse the string, and return it. Finally, all strings are concatenated together with `join` (with newlines).

Also, here is another (and probably less efficient) recursive solution:

```
def hola(count)
  if count == 0
    ''
  elsif count.even?
    "Hola mi amigo".reverse + "\n" + hola(count - 1)
  else
    "Hola mi amigo" + "\n" + hola(count - 1)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

### Solution 1

I'm surprised no one else has proposed a solution with [`Enumerable#cycle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle) (perhaps @CarySwoveland is on vacation):

```
def hola(str, count) 
  [ str, str.reverse ].cycle.take(count).join("\n")
end

puts hola("Hola mi amigo", 1)
# => Hola mi amigo

puts hola("Hola mi amigo", 2)
# => Hola mi amigo
#    ogima im aloH

puts hola("Hola mi amigo", 3)
# => Hola mi amigo
#    ogima im aloH
#    Hola mi amigo

puts hola("Hola mi amigo", 8)
# => Hola mi amigo
#    ogima im aloH
#    Hola mi amigo
#    ogima im aloH
#    Hola mi amigo
#    ogima im aloH
#    Hola mi amigo
#    ogima im aloH
```

### Solution 2

It occurred to me that perhaps OP was actually looking for a recursive solution, as they wrote in the title:

```
def hola(str, count)
  return "" if count <= 0
  str + "\n" + hola(str.reverse, count - 1).chomp
end
```

Output is the same as above. Obviously it's not as efficient, but otherwise I rather like it.

Comment: Whoops. Thanks; fixed.

Comment: Shouldn’t it have `end.chomp` as the last line, since OP requested the result having no trailing carriage return?

Comment: Good catch, @mudasobwa. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Uhhhm. This edit won’t do a trick. `str << ("\n" << hola(str.reverse, count - 1)).chomp` would. (`<<` vs. `+` is unrelated, it is just a matter of my habit.)

Comment: And yet, it does work.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity:

```
str = '¡Hola mi amigo!'
([str, str.reverse] * (count / 2 + 1)).take(count).join $/
([str] * count).map.with_index { |s, i| i.even? ? s : s.reverse }.join $/
([str] * count).each.with_index.with_object("") do |(s, i), acc|
  acc << (i.even? ? s : s.reverse) << $/
end.strip
```

To make it more robust (credits to Cary,) one might prepare reversed string in advance.

Comment: That's a lot of reversin' the same string.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yeah, and more of unnecessary intermediate objects creating. The reason was to show different approaches. I always prepend my answers, that are not intended to be used as is with a disclaimer “Just out of curiosity.”

Answer (score 1):

```
def alternate(str, count)
  (("%s\n%s\n" % [str, str.reverse])*(count/2) << str*(count % 2)).chomp
end

str = "Hola mi amigo"

puts alternate(str, 4)  
Hola mi amigo
ogima im aloH
Hola mi amigo
ogima im aloH

puts alternate(str, 5)  
Hola mi amigo
ogima im aloH
Hola mi amigo
ogima im aloH
Hola mi amigo
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced with Ruby in particular, but from some light searching, I'd use the .reverse method and for-loops inside your elsif statements. It shouldn't be too hard to put together.

A bit of .reverse documentation can be found here:

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2314083&seqNum=29